# Single Webpage which you can't close. Only full-screen and play video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

So I'm doing webpages for artists for an exhibition coming up. These have been completed but now they've also asked that each of their pieces will have a laptop in front of them.

On the laptop will be a single webpage which has a video on it that contains information about their piece...easy enough.

However they also want that laptop to pretty much be completely unusable apart from display that page.

The "User" will only be able to:

1. Un/Full-screen the video.
2. Un/Full-Screen the browser window.
3. Play/Pause the video.
4. If the user tries to navigate to another site = redirects to that webpage.
5. The window cannot be closed either.

Any advice? I assume this can't be done with pure PHP/CSS/jQuery/HTML?

Comment: nope... security and usability restraints. You would probably have to do some kind of desktop app.

Comment: What sort of language would this be in and what sort of development time would you say it would take?

Comment: It would probably be a WinForms app (not sure about language, probably determined by preference), and I couldn't be sure about development time since I do not work in this language. Surely it couldn't be anything too much, given the requirements of the design

Comment: I might would write a simple video player in Java or something. OR buy some kiosk software that actually locks down the whole computer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using Chrome's kiosk mode - instructions for enabling here: http://lifehacker.com/use-chromes-kiosk-mode-to-limit-someones-access-to-yo-1243433249

Comment: I've just attempted this and it...simply doesn't work for me. I added --kiosk http://www.whatismyip.com as a test. Chrome opens, site gets displayed but no full screen/kiosk mode

Comment: Did you close out of all running Chrome instances before launching it?

Comment: per your link kiosk mode does not prevent alt-f4

Answer (score 0):

Somebody asked how he could show a website in a desktop application some time ago. I posted the sourcecode as an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17226369/2373114].)
Also I found [this](http://sysadministrivia.blogspot.de/2012/05/creating-kiosk-machine-with-windows-7.html?m=1) which seems like it could help you.